# How can the rest of the crew understand Neelix when stranded during "Basics"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

During the two-part episode "[Basics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basics_(Star_Trek:_Voyager))" the crew of Voyager get stranded on a remote planet and have all technology (including tricorders and comm badges) confiscated from them.

Assuming that they no longer have universal translators, how do the crew communicate with Neelix and Kes?

Have Neelix and Kes learnt English whilst on-board Voyager?

Comment: Or each other, even? Do the feds learn a common "Federation" language, or even the Earthers learn a common "Earth" language or do they all rely on the universal translators?

Comment: @colmde That is an excellent point

Answer (score 23):

Considering that they could not understand the language of the natives of that planet the only logical conclusion is that Neelix and Kes at some point learned English.

The Trek writers seemed to forget the universal translator was a piece of technology fairly often though.

Comment: To be honest, the whole tackling of the language barrier in Trek is lacklustre at best and nonsensical at worst. The only way it could be made to make sense to me now is if they all have Babelfish ;)

Comment: Maybe TARDIS was stationed nearby.

Comment: I thought the Universal Translators were implants? Glad to think I wasn't the only one to catch BBCA ST:VOY Marathon!

Comment: The UT is a pretty ridiculous piece of tech, if you think about it.  It can translate (almost) any language, including those of species the Federation has *literally never met before* immediately, in real-time.  That means it can somehow deduce the meaning of words it has never heard before and convert them into a language the Feds understand.  If you consider that alien sentence structure is not the same as ours, that also means it's deducing *words the alien hasn't spoken yet* in order to generate a grammatically correct English sentence.  It basically needs to be reading their minds.

Comment: @Steve-O and that's what [Babel fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_races_and_species_in_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Babel_fish) mentioned in first comment is doing, exactly.

Comment: @Steve-O It's something I'm willing to overlook though, because treating it realistically would make the stories unbearably impractical.

Comment: True it's a plot device, but sometimes the UT not working is a plot device (e.g. DS9's  "Little Green Men") so the original question is fair. I believe in "The 37s" it was established that they are in the comm badges though that's a memory from long ago so I could be wrong.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Agreed, 100%.  The show would be unwatchable if we had to wait for every alien to finish speaking gibberish before an English translation came out.  My point was basically the same as yours - we have to handwave some things to keep the show entertaining to watch.

Comment: @colmde In the episode from DS9 you quote, the UTs are shown to be in their ears (but quite easy to access).

Comment: @yanyankelevich - In the Ferengis' ears yes, but the Starfleet UTs (I think) are said to be in the comm badges in the Voyager episode I quote.

Comment: @Steve-O A lot of it is handwaved, but my understanding is that the basic premise behind the UT is the idea that certain concept and roots in thoughts occur across languages, so by analyzing the frequency of words or sounds within speech it's possible to get a basic translation. As I remember, in ENT, the UT got substantially better as it encountered more and more races and got a better understanding of the themes running through all languages. Remember, all sentient races in the Alpha Quadrant come from the same genetic ancestors.